# (ms4w) oracle spatilal problem of drawing compound polygon for Oracle 10g

Tags: mapserver, oracle-spatial, ms4w

When i draw a compound polygon

SDO_GEOMETRY(
    2003,  -- two-dimensional polygon
    NULL,
    NULL,
    SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1005,2, 1,2,1, 5,2,2), -- compound polygon
    SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(6,10, 10,1, 14,10, 10,14, 6,10)
  )

by using msw4 accompanied with mapserver 5.4 or the previous version, they are successful to create an image.

But when i change to msw4 3.0.6 with mapserver 6.0.3 (libmap.dll of Oracle 11g), i always get the problem :

msDrawShape(): General error message. Only polygon shapes can be drawn using a POLYGON layer definition.

I think it comes from the file libmap.dll, maybe libmap.dll for Orl 11g doesn't work welll with Orc 10g

Can you suggest me what to do ?

Iam using Oracle client 10.2.0.3, and the underlying database is Oracle db 10g (10.2.0.4)

Answer (score 1):

My experience is as yours: Mapserver used to support Oracle compound polygons in previous versions, but they withdrew the support in present versions. So as far as I know, it is not an Oracle version issue. So far we have resorted to an older version of Mapserver to be able to render compound polygons. I have no idea when Mapserver will support these more complex geometries again.